# Calling several functions as promises get Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I tried to write this code very simple to focus on solving the problem, but what I really want is for one nodejs controller to call another more advanced nodejs controller multiple times.

This is my **Route**

```
// test Route
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var testController = require('../controllers/testController');

router.get('/getTest', function(req, res) {
    testController.getTest(req, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my **testController.js**

```
exports.getTest = function(req, res) {

    var myArray = [300,200,400,100,500];
    var myResult = [];


    // Find all data based on myArrau
    var findData = function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
            callDataController(i, myArray[i]);
        }
        resolve();
    })};


    // Call and get the specific data
    var dataController = require('./dataController');
    var callDataController = function(i, myValue) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dataController.getData (
            { "myValue": myValue }, res, 
            function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    myResult[i] = data;  
                    resolve(data);
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('ERR dataController: ' + err));
                };
            });
    })};


    // Send result to page
    var sendResult = function(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            res.json({error:false, "myResult":myResult})
            resolve();
        });
    };


    // Run promises
    findData()
        .then(sendResult)
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("getTest ERR: " + err);
            res.json({error:true,err})
        }
    )
}
```

And this is my **dataController** which usually do a lot of mongodb work

```
exports.getData = function(req, res) {
    console.log("Data received: " + JSON.stringify(req, null, 4));

    console.log("Doing lots of mongodb work taking milliseconds to minutes")
    setTimeout(function(){},req.myValue);

    res.json({error:false,  "myValue":req.myValue+1000 })
 }
```

And here comes the problem, best explained by the terminal console.log

```
Data received: {
    "myValue": 300
}
Do a LOT of mongodb work taking anywhere from milliseconds to minutes
Data received: {
    "myValue": 200
}
Do a LOT of mongodb work taking anywhere from milliseconds to minutes
Data received: {
    "myValue": 400
}
Do a LOT of mongodb work taking anywhere from milliseconds to minutes
Data received: {
    "myValue": 100
}
Do a LOT of mongodb work taking anywhere from milliseconds to minutes
Data received: {
    "myValue": 500
}
Do a LOT of mongodb work taking anywhere from milliseconds to minutes
GET /testRoute/getTest 304 8.448 ms - -
getTest ERR: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:9976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:9976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:9976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:9976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
(node:9976) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 6): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Even if I only put one value in myArray I still get the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

This is the one point of async which I just cant get to work. 
(already tried adding them all to a Promise.all array, same problem)

Comment: What you try to do in `findData` is absolutely not how promises work. Check `Promise.all`.

Comment: `sendResult` is synchronous and should not use promises at all.

Comment: You're responding using `res` in so many places its getting called multiple times within a single request to `/testRoute/getTest`, it would be much easier if you handled the outcome of the promise returned by `getTest()` and then responded accordingly within the Router itself.  Plus you have a number of problems with your Promise usage as @bergi is saying.

Comment: @Bergi I tried already - added all the calls to the `callDataController` function to a Promise.all - but I keep getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: There's a severe mismatch between `getData` and `callDataController`. The one just sends the result to the client (and will do that every time it is called!), while the other expects to get its callback called.

Comment: @peteb ahhh ok I think I understand what you mean there.

Comment: @Bergi Sorry but I am not sure I understand.  is there something I forget in the return to `callDataController` ?

Comment: @Bergi you are the Promise master (read a lot of your great posts) - how would you do multiple calls to another controller in an async environment?   Is there a better way than what I try here?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard No, your `callDataController` should be fine once you switch back to `Promise.all` (you probably had that correct, you might want to post it). Your problem is the `getData` method, which *doesn't `return` anything* but instead just writes to the response. It should return a promise for the result of the mongodb work. It should not even receive the `res` as a parameter

Comment: @Bergi Ahh ok I will try working some more with Promise.all.   The problem is that if I remove "res" then it wont work when I call it. Instead I get a `TypeError: res.json is not a function` in `getData`s catch

Comment: @torbenrudgaard That's not the problem, that's the solution. Remove that call. `getData` should not - **must not** - write to `res`!

Comment: @Bergi  
When I do this, I can send data to getData and receive a result back. 
`dataController.getData ( { "myValue": myValue }, res, function(err, data) {`
 

But when I remove res like this, 
`dataController.getData ( { "myValue": myValue }, function(err, data) {`

I can still send getData but instead of a result I get `TypeError: res.json is not a function` 

In my mind you are correct, the `function(err, data)` should be enough to get the result. So how can I avoid the type error?

Comment: Remove the entire `res.json(…)` line!

Comment: @Bergi done,  removed the res.json from getData (that one was causing the error).  But how do I get getData to send its result back to the caller?  I tried `return ({error:false,  "myValue":req.myValue+1000 });` without luck - is there another way instead of res.json?

Comment: `res.json` didn't return anything, which was the problem. You should create a `new Promise` in there and call `resolve()` with the result, then `return` the promise from the function.

Comment: @Bergi you did it again!! - As soon as I got rid of the res in the caller and res.json in the receiver, everything worked, alle promises worked, and I can even return data with callback or with a resolve.  Now I understand why you kept focusing on that "res" thingy - cause that WAS the problem, not all the other stuff that I focused on :)  I spent 12 hours today fighting with that "res" thing - and all I had to do was KILL IT :-)  Thanks again Mr. Promise.Yoda :-D   Put a solution so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Bergi one followup.  When doing all these nodejs controllers which returns data back to angular, would you completely avoid the res.json and instead use resolve or callback to return the data?  Because res.json has been doing fine until the day when I had to call one controller from another controller, thats when it messed everything up. So what is the "nice" way to "end" a controller and return a response?

Comment: I'd do the `res.json` only in the route, not in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the controller that you're calling multiple times is writing the response to the client - multiple times (or at least, it's trying to). Instead, let it just return a promise, and respond only in the router code:

```
// test Route
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var testController = require('../controllers/testController');
router.get('/getTest', function(req, res) {
    testController.getTest(req).then(function sendResult(myResult) {
         res.json({error:false, "myResult":myResult}))
    }, err => {
        console.log("getTest ERR: " + err);
        res.json({error:true,err});
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

```
// testController.js
var dataController = require('./dataController');
exports.getTest = function(req) {
    var myArray = [300,200,400,100,500];
    var myResult = [];

    // Find all data based on myArrau
    function findData() {
        return myArray.map(callDataController);
    }

    // Call and get the specific data
    function callDataController(myValue, i) {
        return dataController.getData (
            { "myValue": myValue }
        ).catch(function(err) {
            throw new Error('ERR dataController: ' + err)
        });
    };

    // Run promises
    return Promise.all(findData());
}
```

```
// dataController
exports.getData = function(req) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Data received: " + JSON.stringify(req, null, 4));

        console.log("Doing lots of mongodb work taking milliseconds to minutes")
        setTimeout(function(){
            resolve({error:false, "myValue":req.myValue+1000 });
        }, req.myValue);
    });
};
```

Comment: So simple and elegant - once again thank you so much Bergi!!!  I learn a lot from you!

Comment: one question.  Say I want to do something with the data in the callDataController before I return it.  `return dataController.getData ( { "myValue": data } ).catch(function(err) {`  how do I do that?

Comment: You insert a `.then(result => …)` in the chain

Comment: Of cause! :-D  I have to start looking at promise functions the right way!!